# how to set adaptive layout at run time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, adaptive-design

how to set adaptive layout at run time?

I am developing iOS app using adaptive layout with multiple views. I want to change the views position when keyboard will pop up.

I am using below auto layout coding it was not working.

```
NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-vSpacing-[redView]-vSpacing-|"                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                    metrics:metrics
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hSpacing-[redView]-hSpacing-|"
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                    metrics:metrics
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the constant value for the constraint at runtime. Take outlet for top layout constraint (viewTopLayoutConstraint) for the view.

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
    {
        _viewTopLayoutConstraint.constant = -100;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand, kindly provide full code